# Restoring an extracted sub-matrix after necessary modification into the original matrix from which it is extracted using Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a huge 2D matrix.
After extracting as many as possible sub-matrices of size 8*8 from this 2D matrix, i made certain necessary modifications in the sub-matrices.
Now i want to re-constitute the original 2D matrix by replacing the extracted sub-matrices with the corresponding new modified sub-matrices.
The positions of each of the elements in both the extracted sub matrix as well as the corresponding new modified sub matrix should be the same in the original 2D matrix.
How can i do this using Matlab?
Thank you.

Comment: it will help if you post small code example to show the problem. It is very easy to do many advanced matrix operations in Matlab. Also, there is no need to really 'extract' the sub-matrices to modify them, then 'put them' back in. You could have done everything on the main matrix itself. You can use simple [A;B;C] to build a matrix from smaller matrices, and many other ways.

Comment: But i will just make changes in few of the sub-matrices and not change all them. In that case i would have to extract them and make the changes separately.

Comment: So, could you please tell me that after making the changes, how can i just put the modified sub-matrices back into their original positions?

Answer (score 1):

```
% let's generate a big 100x100 matrix
big_matrix = rand(100, 100);

% the indices of an exemplary small matrix
sm_x = 20:27;
sm_y = 20:27

% the small matrix
small_matrix = big_matrix(sm_x:sm_y);

% let's modify the small matrix - replace this line with your own code
small_matrix(small_matrix > 0.5) = 1;

% let's write the modified small matrix back to the original position
big_matrix(sm_x:sm_y) = small_matrix;
```